# PySide Qt dataChanged.emit() not working but LayoutChanged.emit works

Tags: python, qml, pyside6

```
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine, qmlRegisterType
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject, Signal, Slot, Property, Qt,QUrl, QTimer, QAbstractListModel


class CpuLoadModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QAbstractListModel.__init__(self)

        self.__update_timer = QTimer(self)
        self.__update_timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.__update_timer.timeout.connect(self.__update)
        self.__update_timer.start()

        self.todos = []

    def __update(self):
        self.todos.append(random.randint(0, 99))
        self.layoutChanged.emit()
        print(self.todos)
        self.dataChanged.emit(self.index,self.index,[])

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            text = self.todos[index.row()]
            print(f"Text: {index.row()} role : {role}")
            print("--------")
            return text

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self.todos)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    qmlRegisterType(CpuLoadModel, 'PsUtils', 1, 0, 'CpuLoadModel')
    engine.load(QUrl("main.qml"))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

self.dataChange.emit method is not working at all, however self.LayoutChange.emit works but with those mistakes from qml

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
```

Comment: show the -.qml...

Comment: Why are you emitting `dataChanged` using `self.index`, which is a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layoutChanged signal must be emitted when something in the model has changed (for example it has been reordered), and dataChanged when any of the items change data but none of them is used to indicate that a row was added, in that case it must use the beginInsertRows and endInsertRows methods.

```py
def __update(self):
    self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), self.rowCount(), self.rowCount())
    self.todos.append(random.randint(0, 99))
    self.endInsertRows()
```

Also change to:

```py
def rowCount(self, index=QModelIndex()):
    if index.isValid():
        return 0
    return len(self.todos)
```

Comment: I still have this error message after a while: file:///Users/david/opt/Qt6 Projects/CpuLoads beta /main.qml:18: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
Text: 29 role : 0
--------
Text: 29 role : 0

Comment: @DavidLeopoldie Please provide a [mre], share the main.qml

Answer (score 0):

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

import PsUtils 1.0

Window {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: "CPU Load"

    ListView {
        id:listviewId
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: CpuLoadModel { }
        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: listviewId.width
            height: 30;
            color: "white"

            Rectangle {
                id: bar
                width: listviewId.width * display / 100.0
                height: 30
                color: "green"
            }

            Text {
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                x: Math.min(bar.x + bar.width + 5, parent.width-width)
                text: display + "%"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically the mistake was the parent.width in QML we better off to use id to refer to element instead of using parent.width ( use elementId.width)

Comment: For future reference please provide what is being asked, otherwise we cannot give proper and complete answers. We asked you two things you never answered to, including a [mre] (*including* the qml) which had to be embedded in the *question*, not in an answer that has no reference in its question. We cannot work with incomplete information.